# Raphael not finding element on asp.net page using jquery

Tags: jquery, raphael

I'm a newbie to Raphael and having problems creating a Raphael object from an existing element.

Code below shows what I have tried and the errors each one creates.  Ideally I'd want to use jquery to create the object in the initial call to Raphael.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Fleetstar.UI.WebForm2" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script src="js/raphael.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var thisWorks = document.getElementById('imgMap');     // This works 
        var thisAlsoWorks = $('.mapClass');          //thsi.works
        var thisDoeNotWorkA = Raphael(document.getElementById('imgMap'), 200, 200);   //Error: Unexpected call to method or property access.
        var thisDoeNotWorkB = Raphael(document.getElementById('imgMap')[0], 200, 200);  //Error: 'tagName' is null or not an object
        var thisDoeNotWorkC = Raphael(document.getElementById('imgMap').node, 200, 200);  //// Error: 'tagName' is null or not an object
        var thisDoeNotWorkD = Raphael($('.mapClass'), 200, 200);            //Error: 'container' is null or not an object
        var thisDoeNotWorkE = Raphael($('.mapClass').node, 200, 200);   // Error: 'tagName' is null or not an object
        var thisDoeNotWorkF = Raphael($('.mapClass')[0], 200, 200);    //Error: Unexpected call to method or property access.
        var thisDoeNotWorkG = Raphael($('[id$="imgMap"]'), 200, 200);    // Error: 'container' is null or not an object
        var thisDoeNotWorkH = Raphael($('[id$="imgMap"]')[0], 200, 200);   //Error: Unexpected call to method or property access.
        var thisDoeNotWorkI = Raphael($('[id$="imgMap"]').node, 200, 200);   //Error: 'tagName' is null or not an object

    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
<img class="mapClass" id="imgMap" name="imgMapName" style="position: absolute" src="Images/map.gif"
    alt="" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var thisDoeNotWorkA = Raphael('imgMap', 200, 200);
```

The spec at http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael says you want to pass the node id.

EDIT: If that doesn't work then it is possible that the element ID was modified by something else?

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen anyone try to make a Raphael canvas from an image tag.
Why don't you use an ordinary div and position it where you like?

thisDoesWork = Raphael(document.getElementById('imgMapDiv'), 200, 200);

Charles

http://www.irunmywebsite.com